# How to create product using SOAP API magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, api, soap

I want to create product and update product using **`SOAP API`** , can anyone guide me how to do it with **Magento 2**.

I am using bellow code to create product

```
$wsdl = "http://thebetaserver.in/magento2/soap/default?services=catalogProductRepositoryV1";
$xml_post_string = '<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:def="http://thebetaserver.in/magento2/soap/default?services=catalogProductRepositoryV1">

<soap:Header/>
<soap:Body>
    <def:catalogProductRepositoryV1SaveRequest>
        <product>
            <sku>1005001</sku>
            <name>TEST PRODUCT</name>
            <attributeSetId>4</attributeSetId>
            <price>19.99</price>
            <status>1</status>
            <visibility>4</visibility>
            <typeId>simple</typeId>
            <weight>1</weight>
        </product>
    </def:catalogProductRepositoryV1SaveRequest>
</soap:Body>
```

```
$headers = array(
    "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
    "Accept: text/xml",
    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    "Pragma: no-cache",
    "Authorization: Bearer j7yny07y4ha209r7dqml3yt4kirvgclb",
    "Content-length: " . strlen($xml_post_string),
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $wsdl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_post_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$fp = fopen("soap.xml", "w");
fwrite($fp, $result);
fclose($fp);

var_dump($result);
```

But I am getting below error.

> **string(299) " rpc:ProcedureNotPresentProcedure not present "**

Comment: Di you find a solution?

Comment: Navin & Juliano Vargas Did you find a solution?